Image Slider Not Appearing
I've created an image slider for my website.


var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('radio-button' + count).checked = true;
  count ++;
  if(count > 5){
    count = 1;
  }
}, 5000);
.slider {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-manual {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.manual-button {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 15px;
}

.manual-button:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

#radio-button1:checked~.one {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio-button2:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio-button3:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -40%;
}

#radio-button4:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -60%;
}

#radio-button5:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -80%;
}

.slide-automatic {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  bottom:0;

}

.slide-automatic div {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1S;
  margin: 15px;
}

#radio-button1:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button1 ,
#radio-button2:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button2 ,
#radio-button3:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button3 ,
#radio-button4:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button4 ,
#radio-button5:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button5 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button1">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button2">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button3">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button4">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button5">

      <div class="slide one">
       <a href="#"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/760/500" alt="#"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
       <a href="#"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/764/500" alt="#"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
       <a href="#"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/765/500" alt="#"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
       <a href="#"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/767/500" alt="#"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
       <a href="#"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/768/500" alt="#"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="slide-automatic">
        <div class="auto-button1"></div>
        <div class="auto-button2"></div>
        <div class="auto-button3"></div>
        <div class="auto-button4"></div>
        <div class="auto-button5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide-manual">
      <label for="radio-button1" class="manual-button"></label>
      <label for="radio-button2" class="manual-button"></label>
      <label for="radio-button3" class="manual-button"></label>
      <label for="radio-button4" class="manual-button"></label>
      <label for="radio-button5" class="manual-button"></label>
    </div>
  </div>



When I first tested the image slider it was working without any issues. However, when I uploaded it to my website, the image slider didn't appear. On the PC version of the website, it seems to have been overlapped by other content and is almost unviewable. On the mobile version of the website, the images don't appear but still seem to be functioning.
Could my photos cause this issue?
Is there a problem with the image slider itself?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Is the problem visible in the code snippet, or is the snippet working as desired?

Apart from a rather 'messy' return from slide 5 to slide 1, your snippet seems to be working fine so please could you explain in more detail exactly what the problem is so we can help?
